# How to get fields from Running total to minus in formula field in Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, cumulative-sum

I created two fields in Running Total fields (SUMEXSPENCE&SUMRECOVER)
[image]

and then I want to take these two field to minus in Formula Fields (MinusExpenseRecovery).

[image]

So how can I do that? And one more question, sometimes when loop data sumrecovery is null. So how can I set condition in formula?

Thanks in advance

Comment: sumexpence-sumrecovery write in formula filed

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are already at the answer - Create two running totals, one to sum the expense and another to sum the recovery. Be sure to set the "Reset" property correctly.

1. Create a running total to SUM the Expense field
   [image]
2. Create a running total to SUM the Recovery field
3. Create a formula with this code `{#sum_recovery} - {#sum_expense}`
4. Place the formula in the report

[image]